# Azure Scheduler: first working day of every month

Tags: azure, azure-scheduler

We are using Azure Scheduler API to create scheduling job on Azure Scheduler. We got the new request to create a recurring job that happens at the FIRST WORKING day of every month.

Normally it will be on the 1st day of the month. But if the 1st of the month is Saturday, the first working day will be 3rd (Monday). Or, the 1st day of the month is Sunday, the first working day will be 2nd (Monday). Like the table below:

[image]

Is this possible in Azure Scheduler? I know if it's possible with cron job like this link:

http://www.switchplane.com/blog/how-to-run-a-cron-job-on-the-first-weekday-of-the-month/

Answer (score 2):

I just had a quick try at this in Azure Portal and while it seems possible to schedule a task on 1st Monday of every month, I don't think it's possible to say 1st Working Day of every month because Azure Scheduler has no idea what the 1st working day for you would be (it could be a Tuesday if you have a holiday on 1st Monday of the month).

[image]

Comment: So if I understand it correctly, **`1st working day`** won't work because you're absolutely right ... it could be a Friday or a Saturday (in UAE for example) and Azure Scheduler has no idea about it (like I mentioned in my answer). However 1st Monday (or for that matter any day of the week would work).

Comment: Yes, the question from @adam.bielasty is perfectly right, I missed this point, so, I unmarked your answer, sorry.

Comment: No need to say sorry:). I guess the simple answer is you can't ask Azure Scheduler to run a task on 1st working day of a month.